# Angular POST - 415 Error (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: angular, api, post

I'm learning Angular and I'm getting 'Unsupported Media Type' - Status 415 when trying to post the data to an API.

I have a page that list some products in a table. There is an add button next to every row. When you click add, it will push the items to the cart. When I go to my cart and view all the items that were added to it, when I try clicking the checkout button and push the data to an API I'm getting that error message.

Here is my Product Component:

```
    export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[] = [];

  constructor(private productService: ProductsService, private cartService: CartService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productService.getProduct()
      .subscribe(
        (sucessResponse) => {
          this.products = sucessResponse;
        })
  }

  addToCart(product: Product) {
    this.cartService.addToCart(product);
  }
}
```

Here is my Product-Service

```
export class ProductsService {
  private baseApiUrl = 'https://localhost:44301/api/Products';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProduct(): Observable<Product[]> {

    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.baseApiUrl);
  }
}
```

Here is my Product-HTML:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th scope="col">Add to Cart</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
      <td>{{product.productName}}</td>
      <td>{{product.price | currency: 'CAD'}}</td>
      <td>{{product.description}}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" (click)="addToCart(product)">Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a list of Cart code:

Cart-Service:

```
export class CartService {
  items: Product[] = [];
  url: string = 'https://localhost:44301/api/OrderDetails';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addToCart(product: Product) {
    this.items.push(product);
  }

  getCartItems() {
    return this.items;
  }

  public addPost(postData: Object) {
    this.http.post(this.url, postData).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

}
```

Cart-Component:

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  private url = 'https://localhost:44301/api/OrderDetails'


  constructor(private cartService: CartService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  items = this.cartService.getCartItems();


  postData(postData: Object) {
    this.cartService.addPost(postData)
  }

}
```

Cart-HTML

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
      <td>{{item.productName}}</td>
      <td>{{item.price | currency: 'CAD'}}</td>
      <td>{{item.description}}</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" (click)="postData(item)">CheckOut</button>
```

Comment: try adding content-type : application/json  to the post. if that works then you should create a http intercepter so you dont need to add it on every service.

Comment: I've added it, and I am getting a different error. If I add a button for each row in my cart and click it, it post to the API for each row. Although that's not what I want. I just want 1 button to POST to the API. I'm assuming I am not getting the data properly to POST to the API?

Answer (score 0):

Gonna move this to answer since its easier to show code

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">  <- item scope starts here
      <td>{{item.productName}}</td>
      <td>{{item.price | currency: 'CAD'}}</td>
      <td>{{item.description}}</td>
    </tr> <- item scope ends here
    
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" (click)="postData(item)">CheckOut</button> <- i dont see anything item scoped here.
```

I think you you have item object out of scope as well, you are probably sending `undefined` to the server hence no json automatically.

Comment: I guess my main question is then, how would I send a POST for each item? If I put the button in the table, it will get looped through and keep adding a button for each row, which I don't want. I just want a main checkout button, which will post each item in the cart.

Comment: Really depends how you wanna do it. In the past i would send the each item added to the server so its on a basket on the server side. So if a user comes back they still have their basket, however that requires the user to login. As i see you have it you keep the basket locally. If you do that that is fine too. but i would have the item id and the item quantity together. This way you not sending all the item data back to the server again.